# Images loading speed dependent on server?

Tags: php

Let's say I'm loading several large images(>500kb) into my elements using php and js, i found that my loading speed takes quite awhile(ard 5 secs).

Last night i was browsing http://ringvemedia.com/beijing-photos

and the loading speed for the full background images is lightning fast. I check out the natural width for the background image is 1024px and the quality is pretty decent, so i think the image's size shouldn't be too small.

So how do i achieve similiar image-loading speed? I'm using a hostgator server btw.

Answer (score 1):

Your image load speed is based on bandwdith, assuming the machine isn't terribly overloaded, which is a possibility in a shared environment (but this should be spotty, sometimes fast, sometimes slow).

If you have say a 2mb pipe upload from your server as part of your hosting plan, well 500kb * 8 bits per byte = 4mb, which means each image takes 2 seconds to transfer.  With large images...transfer can take quite a while, and that's if only one user is getting files at a time.  Do you know what your bandwidth is, and where your server's located?

Based on your description, I would bet your outgoing bandwidth isn't that high, and that's why transferring any decent amount of data will be slower than you'd like.

As a side note: For reference: that site's images are 100-240kb, most on the lower end of that.

Comment: Hey nick,

My plan is under the hatchling plan over at hostgator http://www.hostgator.com/shared.shtml

It says "unlimited bandwidth" but i'm pretty sure that's BS.. The server is mostly to be in US.

As for the ringvemedia's image size, did you use firebug to obtain the size range?

Comment: Your hosting provider is conflating bandwidth with simple traffic per month. Many providers cap out at some number of gigabyte transferred, either shutting down or charging extra. Yours doesn't have a limit like that. But that's not *really* bandwidth, of course. Doesn't do much good if it's unlimited 1200bps.